# locals.tf file - parsing jsonencode body

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Wondering if anyone has ran tackled it. So, I need to be able to generate list of egress CIDR blocks that is currently available for listing over an API. Sample output is the following:

```
[
   {
      "description": "blahnet-public-acl",
      "metadata": {
        "broadcast": "192.168.1.191",
        "cidr": "192.168.1.128/26",
        "ip": "192.168.1.128",
        "ip_range": {
          "start": "192.168.1.128",
          "end": "192.168.1.191"
        },
        "netmask": "255.255.255.192",
        "network": "192.168.1.128",
        "prefix": "26",
        "size": "64"
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "blahnet-public-acl",
      "metadata": {
        "broadcast": "192.168.160.127",
        "cidr": "192.168.160.0/25",
        "ip": "192.168.160.0",
        "ip_range": {
          "start": "192.168.160.0",
          "end": "192.168.160.127"
        },
        "netmask": "255.255.255.128",
        "network": "192.168.160.0",
        "prefix": "25",
        "size": "128"
      }
    }
  ]
```

So, I need convert it to Azure Firewall

```
###############################################################################
# Firewall Rules - Allow Access To TEST VMs
###############################################################################

resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "azure-firewall-azure-test-access" {
  for_each = local.egress_ips
  name                = "azure-firewall-azure-test-rule"
  azure_firewall_name = azurerm_firewall.public_to_test.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  priority            = 105
  action              = "Allow"

  rule {
    name = "test-access"
    source_addresses = local.egress_ips[each.key]
    destination_ports = ["43043"]
    destination_addresses = ["172.16.0.*"]
    protocols = [ "TCP"]
  }
}
```

So, bottom line is that allowed IP addresses have to be a list of strings for the "**source_addresses**" parameter, such as this:

```
["192.168.44.0/24","192.168.7.0/27","192.168.196.0/24","192.168.229.0/24","192.168.138.0/25",]
```

I configured **data_sources.tf** file:

```
data "http" "allowed_networks_v1" {
  url = "https://testapiserver.com/api/allowed/networks/v1"
}
```

...and in **locals.tf**, I need to configure

```
locals {

  allowed_networks_json     = jsondecode(data.http.allowed_networks_v1.body)
  egress_ips = ...
}
```

...and that's where I am stuck. How can parse that data in **locals.tf** file so I can reference it from within TF ?

Thanks a metric ton!!

Comment: Is the `metadata.cidr` what you need to extract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the list of string you are referring to are the objects under: `metadata.cidr` we can extract that with a for loop in a local, and also do a distinct just in case we get duplicates.

Here is a sample code

```hcl
data "http" "allowed_networks_v1" {
  url = "https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/json/networks.json"
}

locals {
  allowed_networks_json = jsondecode(data.http.allowed_networks_v1.body)

  distinct_cidrs = distinct(flatten([
    for key, value in local.allowed_networks_json : [
      value.metadata.cidr
    ]
  ]))
}

output "data" {
  value = local.distinct_cidrs
}
```

and here is the output of a plan on that:

`terraform plan`

```txt
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:

Terraform will perform the following actions:

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + data = [
      + "192.168.1.128/26",
      + "192.168.160.0/25",
    ]
```

---

Here is the code for your second sample:

```hcl
data "http" "allowed_networks_v1" {
  url = "https://raw.githack.com/akamalov/testfile/master/networks.json"
}

locals {
  allowed_networks_json = jsondecode(data.http.allowed_networks_v1.body)

  distinct_cidrs = distinct(flatten([
    for key, value in local.allowed_networks_json.egress_nat_ranges : [
      value.metadata.cidr
    ]
  ]))
}

output "data" {
  value = local.distinct_cidrs
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Helder. Wondering, what TF version are you running, by chance?

Comment: @user2362699 I got `Terraform v0.14.5`

Comment: Thanks So much, Helder!! Can you pleeeease try this file instead: https://raw.githack.com/akamalov/testfile/master/networks.json

Comment: It looks like it is failing to find an attribute because key "cidr" is within an array called "egress_nat_ranges". I tried to change locals.tf entry to "value.egress_nat_ranges.metadata.cidr", but it is not finding it :(

Comment: I added a second sample with `egress_nat_ranges` you needed to add that on the `for`, not in the `value`

Comment: You're super-awesome, Helder! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @user2362699 Don't forget to accept the answer if that solves your problem

Comment: Helder, just a quick question: what if there are two arrays and let's say I want to combine them into the same format long array list? Let's say with 'egress_nat_ranges' and 'express_routes'. Sample is here: https://raw.githack.com/akamalov/testfile/master/networks2.json Can you take a look, whenever you have time, please?

Comment: @user2362699 look into concat: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/concat.html